# Difference between two variables

Tags: r, self-study

In my data set I have two variables: month (March or April) and wind direction (N, NE, E, SE, S, SW, W, NW). I have to know if there is a difference in wind direction between these months. What kind of test statistic should I use? (I work in R.)

Here's some more information: 
The data is from a study that examines the extent to which background noise in a certain neighborhood depends on the time and certain weather conditions.
The question is: Determine the dominant wind direction in the month 
March and April? Is there a difference in wind direction between these months? 
For the first question, I thought I just needed to look at `table(month, wind direction)`.

The data consist of 2357 measurements of eight variables (month, day, hour, weekday, background noise, wind direction, windspeed and wind angles) that were registered every hour of 50 days in March and April 2010 in the backyard of a particular house.

http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/attachment/4700349/0/achtergrondlawaai.txt

Comment: Can't post this as a comment, but perhaps you can provide little more detail. For example, is the wind direction data a series of observations over a day, week, or month? Or is it the most common direction for the month? Is it count data? Does the windspeed matter? Depending on the answers to the above, a Chi-square or ANOVA may be applicable. Either of these are readily implemented in R ([ANOVA](http://www.statmethods.net/stats/anova.html) [Chi-square](http://www.r-tutor.com/elementary-statistics/goodness-fit/chi-squared-test-independence)).

Comment: None of these suggestions address the circular nature of the data. ANOVA is wrong in principle as means of circular data can produce nonsense.

Comment: Whether windspeed is known as well as direction is indeed a key detail. Whether speed should be analysed together with direction depends on the scientific question to be addressed.

Comment: I've added a relevant tag, but also suggest that the title here is not informative and is likely to bemuse or even mislead future searchers who have entirely different problems (to do with categorical data).

Comment: I don't see that your research problem, as you've stated it, obliges you to pose this question at all. When the wind was blowing might have some indirect relevance because weather does vary seasonally.

Comment: It's hard to explain without data. I want to add my data, but I don't no how.

Comment: http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2033/can-i-post-my-real-data

Comment: Best not to assume that people understand the software you happen to use.

Comment: Noise is the response variable, it seems. Then time of year (fraction of year elapsed), time of week, time of day might all be pertinent. March vs April is not unless you expect some jump on 1 April. $24 \times 50$ I get to be $1200$. I don't know what wind angle is.

Comment: Good point about the circular nature of the data.

Comment: I work with the data 'achtergrondlawaai', added in this link : http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Problem-with-td4700349.html

Comment: sorry, indeed the data is measured every 10 min (but not every day). By 'wind angle' I mean: angle in degrees from which the wind is blowing, compared to a reference position.

Comment: So, you have wind direction measured to the nearest degree. In that case, the eight directions N .. NW are just coarse summaries that can be ignored except if simple summaries are needed. It remains my view that comparing directions between months is a fairly pointless question, so although there might be other views I don't think I can add more to this thread.

Comment: The question is for an assignment for school, it can be a fairly pointless question. 
Is it possible this is the right answer?: > table(month, wind direction).
# so in March , the prevailing wind is from SW, based on the highest number + 
# in April it is N and NE.

Now make a new variable (for example 'month3)') only with the values of March (3) en a new variable ('month4') only with April (4).
> table(month3, wind direction) and
> table(month4, wind direction)
Now compare these two tables...?
Or is there a test to compare these? Anova doesn't work, Chisq.test, prop.test...

Comment: Looking at the frequencies of winds from the 8 compass points is a first (really, at best a zeroth) descriptive step. Whether it's what your teacher wants I (we!) really can't say. A chi-square test doesn't make any use of the ordering or circularity of categories, so it misses much of the information in the data, but it's not fallacious. ANOVA is nonsense, as already pointed out. You should tag your question "self-study" and read the associated Wiki.

Answer (score 7):

Wind direction in essence isn't qualitative. The use of abbreviations and the division of the compass into 8 classes are just conventions used by you or by whoever collected the data. Wind direction underneath that is a quantitative variable, specifically a **directional** variable and more specifically yet **circular** data. That gives you some keywords with which to search. Terminology aside, the key defining characteristic that should drive data analysis is the circularity of the scale so that e.g. $0^\circ$ and $360^\circ$ are identical, which must be respected in analysis.

How to deal with circular data in R (or any other specific software) is off-topic here but there are certainly dedicated packages, and indeed a dedicated book [by Arthur Pewsey and friends](http://ukcatalogue.oup.com/product/9780199671137.do)

Testing for a difference in wind directions between March and April in wind directions strikes me, scientifically, as an artificial problem, because  the conventional divisions of the calendar have no intrinsic meteorological or climatological significance. That's not to say that wind direction might not vary systematically with time of year.

If you have daily data, then it's best to work with those. It seems that for some reason you have data only for two months; even then, plotting and more generally analysing in terms of time of year (e.g. days since 1 January) is a much better way to think about seasonal variations.

If your data arise aggregated by month, and that's not reversible, I will still stress that there is only indirect meaning to the question.

If you wish to persevere with a two-sample test, then various tests associated with the names of Watson, Kuiper and Wheeler-Watson-Mardia (or the same names in different order) are among those available. Strictly, daily measurements of direction are unlikely to be independent, which is not addressed by those tests.

Comment: I don't think this has something to do with 'circular data', never heard of it. Probably the answer to my question is not very difficult (this is just my first semester of biostatistic, I'm a sophomore in biochemistry)

Comment: Whether or not you have heard about something does not determine its applicability to your problem!  Nick Cox provides useful guidance and accurate commentary here (+1).

Comment: On the contrary, comparing wind directions is smack in the middle of circular data analysis. But it still seems marginal to your problem as it is unfolding.

Answer (score -2):

I think that the solution would consist of two steps (unless you need something more complex):

- convert these categorical variables into numeric ones (using `cut()`,
  for example);
- perform a Student's [t-test](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/t.test.html) for both samples.

Comment: Not so; this is entirely unsound. What mean would you assign to directions of $355^\circ$ and $5^\circ$ (or even NE and NW)? t-tests do not respect the circular nature of directional data.

Comment: @NickCox: I believe that directional data, including circular one, can be quantified. A particular coding scheme would depend on the required accuracy - if researcher doesn't care about degrees, but NE/NW/etc. directions, then corresponding degree ranges should be encoded per this scheme. Alternatively, if higher accuracy is required and was used to measure the data, then it should be used (with pre-analysis transformation of 360 to 0 or vice versa). After encoding, it's just numeric data with means, which can be analyzed and interpreted, according to the scheme above.

Comment: I am agreeing with the scope for quantification entirely; see my answer. But in  general, **there is no satisfactory method for comparing means of directional data that doesn't use a definition of mean specific to such data**. There is an entire literature on this, with numerous monographs, for all that it is little known by people who don't use this kind of data.

Comment: The Wikipedia article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_statistics  isn't especially useful here but it does flag the specific class of problems.

Comment: @NickCox: Fair enough, thank you for clarification! Upvoting your answer and comments. Will review the sources you've suggested. By the way, I've found a paper on comparing time series in R, but didn't shared that in my answer, as I doubt that time series are directly applicable in this case.

Comment: Thanks. There is a small literature on directional time series. If data are seasonal too, as is the case here, then the sample space is very interesting (and by most standards unusual).

Comment: @NickCox: You're welcome. It seems that directional statistics is a rather specialized area of statistics, but interesting and useful in obvious domains. The Wikipedia article is a good starting point for enabling my awareness of that area.